# How can I update my Window via AppDelegate in macOS Cocoa?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appdelegate

I am using ViewController for my app content, I want be able to update my app window in AppDelegate. I know that I can update my window from ViewController but for this question I want update my window from AppDelegate while ViewController is going take care of content of my app.

```
import Cocoa

@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    let window: NSWindow? = NSApp.mainWindow

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application

        window?.center()
        window?.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")

        window?.title = "changed label"
        window?.styleMask.remove(.closable)
        window?.styleMask.remove(.fullScreen)
        window?.styleMask.remove(.miniaturizable)
        window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your goal? You can access the window just as you show in your code to update it any way you wish. But it's better to write a window controller and view controller.

Comment: The goal is to access the window that created with ViewController via AppDelegate and making the needed updates in question, can you solve the issue?

Comment: You're updating the autosave name, title and style mask of the window. What else do you want to update?

Comment: @Willeke: Have you tried to run my codes in question? because it does not update my window! If I was able to update my window via AppDelegate and the codes I showed you in question, why would I needed ask this question?

Comment: Is `window` `nil`?

Answer (score 0):

Add a declaration for your view controller and then add it to the window; (example)

```
   var myVC = aViewController()
```

inside applicationDidFinishLaunching;

```
   window?.contentView?.addSubview(aVC.view)
```

Comment: I am sorry your answer is unclear for me, could you put your code in codes of question? Having 2 lines of codes from you cannot help me at moment.

Comment: the declaration goes right after your let window....
and the addSubview goes along with your other modifications to window?....
of course you have you replace 'aViewController' with your own window controller class name.

Comment: Is `aViewController` a view controller or window controller?